# Loader mListener (LoaderInfo) is null when device rotation

Tags: android, android-sqlite, loader

My application use an AsyncTaskLoader to query and load from database. User can filter data by categories. It works fine when no device rotation happened, but the Loader does not load any data that filter by category after device orientation changed.

My code is:

```
//In activity oncreate
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader (0, null, controller);
```

on user filter action, I call:

```
loader.onCententChanged();
```

I put a break point at above line and point out that in the loader instance, its `mListener` is NULL so the call `onCententChanged()` won't deliver result. The `mListener` is not NULL if we don't rotate the device.

Anyone has this issue? Please help!

**EDIT**

Sorry for late reply, I don't see any email from Stackoverflow push, I will check my settings.

By the way, my application use MVC pattern, the controller is for handling data load, event listener, manipulation. In this case, the controller implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.
As I debugged it, set breakpoint and see what happening, I see that the `mListener` member of Loader class is not null when first load in portrait mode but when I turn the device to landscape mode the mListener is NULL so the callback is not call. See the attach image.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_latest_topics_layout);

    // Omitted code

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader (0, null, controller);
}
```

When user filter choose a data filter:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
            .setTitle("Choose a filter")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.latest_episodes_filter_titles, mFilter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ListView listView = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView();
                    mFilter = listView.getCheckedItemPosition();

                    mListHandler.getLoader().onContentChanged();

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
```

Debug: When first time load in portrait/landscape

[image: first time load]

Debug: when rotate device

[image: then rotate device]

Comment: We need to see more of your code: what is `mListener`? Do you handle orientation change yourself?

Comment: @Shywim I added more with images when I debugged it. I don't know why the mListener is NULL so the `onContentChanged` on fire any thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to initialize the loader in the following way. Probably it may help you.

```
//In activity oncreate
if (getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0) == null) {
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, new Bundle(), this);
} else {
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, new Bundle(), this);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Blehi, thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion. The loader is always not null because it is reused by LoaderManager, so the `restartLoader` will call. The problem is my data are big so it takes time to load, I would like it is reused with the loader as Android document state.

Comment: What is your mListHandler? Did you try to call  getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader() instead of mListHandler.getLoader().onContentChanged() in your dialog's onClick listener?

Comment: I got no way other than `restartLoader()` as you suggested for now but I will invest on it in later time. Thanks for your suggestion.